# Is vs will vs get in a sentence

Tags: grammar

I need to convey a message that " if I put a weight on something(assume a newly bought pillow). It is more likely to get torn". My question is of the below sentences which sentence is more accurate for the above scenario and why.

1. If you put a weight on it , it is torn(damaged) easily.
2. If you put a weight on it, it gets torn easily
3. If you put a weight on it, it will get torn easily.
4. If you put a weight on it. It is more likely to be torn
5. If you put a weight on it, it is more likely to get torn
   6.If you put a weight on it, it will torn easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sentence beginning with "if" is a conditional sentence. The verbs that you use depends on the situation that it describes.

For a **universal truth**- something that will always happen, you use present simple:

> If you pour hot water onto ice, the ice **melts**
>   If you put a weight on it, it **tears**.

If you are describing a specific situation, and something will definitely happen, you generally use **will**:

> If you put a weight on it, it will **tear**.

If you are describing a probable consequence of a situation, you generally use present simple and **probably** or **is likely to**.

> If you put a weight on it. It **is likely to** tear.

If you are describing something that might happen anyway, but is more likely to happen in the specified situation, you say **is more likely to**.

> If you put a weight on it. It **is more likely to** tear.

You can express the same idea by saying

> If you put a weight on it. It will tear **more easily**.

Moving on to the question of **get torn** and **be torn**, **get torn** relates to an event- the instant in which tearing takes place. **be torn** can relate either to an event, or to a to a state- the condition that it's in once the tearing has happened.

Consider a glass. An event occurred in which the glass broke. From that time onwards, the state of the glass is .broken.

> The glass **is** broken - *that's the current state of the glass right now*
>   The glass **was** broken yesterday - *could be the state of the glass yesterday and it broke some time before yesterday, or it could describe the event of it being broken, and it happened yesterday.*
>   The glass **broke** yesterday - *describes the event of the glass being broken, and it happened yesterday*
>   The glass **got** broken yesterday - *describes the event of the glass being broken, and it happened yesterday*

In this case, we want to emphasise that the weight is the cause of a tearing event, so it makes more sense to use the **get** version.

> If you put a weight on it, it **gets torn**.
>   If you put a weight on it, it will **get torn**.
>   If you put a weight on it. It **is likely to** get torn.
>   If you put a weight on it. It **is more likely to** get torn.
>   If you put a weight on it. It will get torn **more easily**.

Comment: Great answer however can you please elaborate the last part little more.

Answer (score 2):

*Torn* is the adjective (and past participle), not *torned*, which doesn't exist.

All your sentences are fine when edited like so (using the verb ***to tear*** and the adjective ***torn***):

> If you put a weight on it, it is **torn** easily.
>
> If you put a weight on it, it gets **torn** easily.
>
> If you put a weight on it, it will get **torn** easily.
>
> If you put a weight on it, it is more likely to be **torn**.
>
> If you put a weight on it, it is more likely to get **torn**.
>
> If you put a weight on it, it will **tear** easily.